# Delphi Scripting and ASM

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

I tried

- Pascal Script
- Fast Script
- Script Studio
- IdScript Engine

However none support inline ASM. Is there some library that DOES support it?

Comment: You want to write a script that contains assembly language. You do understand what "script" means don't you? You want to be able to write scripts that compile to raw asm code? Then it's not really scripting any more is it?  Native compilation is not scripting. Scripting is not native compilation. Etc etc.

Comment: Well or porting ASM back to Delphi.. i don't have hours and hours to spend on that.

Comment: First PHP. Then Ruby. Now the full gamut of Pascal based scripts. What problem are you trying to solve? We might be able to give some useful high level guidance.

Comment: If you are still dead set on 64 bit, and your asm is 32 bit which it almost certainly is, you've got a port on your hands. Port to a high level language, not to another asm ghetto.

Comment: He's asking you if you could provide some more details so that there might be some way to accomplish what ever it is that you want to accomplish with a scripting language that is Pascal based, but which allows you to mix inline assembly via ASM, and if he can think of anything that would help you, he'd tell you about it.  Because what you're asking for in your question is a huge (complex, problematic, unworkable) and probably impossible thing. How do you suppose that a scripting engine that compiles and then runs assembly language could do so safely? Check out Google NaCL.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the broader problem that is driving this series of similar questions. Just as Warren says. I suspect that if we knew that we could help you better. I'm trying to help. I've been polite throughout. I don't understand your aggression. Regarding the whole 64/32 bit thing. I note that previous questions indicated that you need 64 bit code. I trust you realise that your 32 bit asm code won't work under 64 bit.

Comment: What do the tags mean? Do you want a solution which works on all of those versions?

Comment: And you understand that you'll need one version of the asm for the 32 bit delphis, and a different version on 64 bit?

Comment: Yes 32 bit asm works on 32 bit compiler and 64 bit on 64 bit compiler.
There is a thing in delphi called $IFDEF ..

Comment: OK. When you said earlier that you wanted to use asm to avoid a port. I wasn't expecting you to have both 32 and 64 bit asm code at hand.

Comment: Joe, the purpose of these comments is to get clarification of the question so that one can be able to answer. Are you suggesting that David be able to answer this very awkward question without clarification?

Comment: Wow.  A scripting language with 32 bit and 64 bit inline assembler, and a precompiler (ifdefs) for scripts.  That is not a scripting language any more. There is however a COMPILER that does that, and even an open source compiler that does that. it's called FreePascal.  So take that, and make something that auto links and runs what you compiled, and you're done, right? Why exactly do you have to use a so-called "script" language?

Comment: Voted Up. I don't understand all this flame. OP has pascal code with ASM blocks and want to execute it in a script with minimal edits. What is wrong with the question?

Comment: PS: Joe, David is not trolling your questions, he is a big part of Stack Overflow's Delphi community, has been here a long time, and has been a significant contribution to other Delphi developers around the world. Please don't assume he's trolling all of your questions just because you see him comment on all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK [DelphiWebScript aka DWScript](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/) supports ASM via it's language extension modules, specifically the [dwsAsmLibModule](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/source/browse/trunk/Libraries/asmLib/dwsAsmLibModule.pas).

**UPDATE**: found an [Eric's blog post](http://delphitools.info/2010/11/18/basm-yes-we-can/) where he describes the feature. Looks like you need to have NASM installed in order to use ASM blocks in DWScript.

Comment: Interesting.. I heard to support asm the code base would require to be  massive like 5-10k lines of code.

Comment: I thought that the ASM directive in DelphiWebScript was for letting you use raw JavaScript inside a DWS, not x86 assembly language.

Comment: @WarrenP, the JavaScript asm part is for the SmartMobileStudio DWS extension. See [from-op4js-to-smart-mobile-studio](http://delphitools.info/2012/05/18/from-op4js-to-smart-mobile-studio/).

Comment: @LURD Seems like you can do this with ScriptStudio by TMS just need to "encapsulate" and it will work.

Comment: @JoeRegan, not sure what you mean. My comment was to Warren about if the asm directive was to embed JavaScript. I scanned the TMS Scripter manual, and there isn't a reference to any asm scripting.

Comment: @ain By the way NASM is 64 bits. So hopefully one day it will be supported in DWS.